# permissions to browse outside of home directory when using Mono to run exe on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, keepass, mono-framework

I'm trying to use Mono to run KeePass.exe on my mac, using the command (from KeePass directory within terminal): `sudo mono keepass.exe`

It runs just fine except for the fact that when browsing to select the kdbx file I can only see the folders within my user home folder.

See Printscreen: Under 'My Computer' there is only 'Personal' which is my home folder

[image]

I guess I'm missing something regarding permissions relating to either  terminal or Mono?

Answer (score 5):

I know exactly what is wrong, I had exactly the same issue!
1.[Downloading WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/download.php?f=WineBottlerCombo_1.7.53.dmg&m=d2luZWJvdHRsZXIua3JvbmVuYmVyZy5vcmcvY29tYm8vYnVpbGRz)(That is a direct link)
2. Open the DMG, and copy Wine and WineBottler to your applications folder.
3. Download the KeePass setup file.
4. Open WineBottler
5. Click advanced in the top bar
6. Make sure it says new prefix
7. Select the box that says "This is the installer, execute it"
8. Locate the KeePassSetup.exe file from within WineBottler
9. Scroll down a little and make sure it includes the open source .Net framework mono
10. Make it include wine.app
11. In winetricks, find and check **dotnet45** (MS .NET 4.0)
12. In winetricks, find and check **forcemono** (Force using Mono ...)
13. Give the app an identifier
14. Build your app!
15. It will take a long while (You may have to download .NET 3.0 and restart the build process)
16. Execute it, and it will copy the prefix.
17. If it closes, open it again
17. If you need plugins, copy them to ~/Library/Applcation Support/ then find the identifier
18. Done

Comment: that's working, great detailed answer. the only drawback from using this approach is that the app which is created weighs almost 1GB.

Comment: I just could not get this to work. All my apps ended up failing or opening to the wine file manager, from which I couldn't figure out what else to do (I tried opening keepass.exe but nothing happened). I am using the latest beta of winebottler, though...

Comment: step 9) scroll down a little bit where??   In the windows your browsing for the exe, or the unmentioned winetricks?  im not seeing it in either, however i have the setup.exe in the Downloads folder, and i DO see the Mono framework down there, cause i downloaded it there.  Confused on that step.

Step 10) where, in windetricks?  its not there, and you didnt mention winetricks of so.?  I have installed it a few times, so not sure where else to look.  AHHH, step 10) Include Wine Binaries.  Step 9 the only problem left here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to the problem - what can be done is creating a symbolic link to the folder which contains the key file (using terminal) and then it is possible to access the linked folder through that symbolic link.

Command in terminal:

`ln -s [path of the folder which contains the key file] [path of the symbolic link which will be created]`

Example:

`ln -s "/Volumes/WinPartition/Data/PasswordFolder ~/Desktop/PasswordLink`